# GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DUPLICATE_ATTACHMENT_EXT errors

Tags: opengl, fbo

I'm using [FBO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object)s in my OpenGL code and I'm seeing compilation errors on `GL\_FRAMEBUFFER\_INCOMPLETE\_DUPLICATE\_ATTACHMENT\_EXT`. What's the cause of this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of this error is an older version of NVIDIA's **glext.h**, which still has this definition. Whereas the most recent versions of [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) don't. This leads to compilation errors in code that you had written previously or got from the web.

The **GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DUPLICATE_ATTACHMENT_EXT** definition for FBO used to be present in the specification (and hence in header files). But, it was later removed. The reason for this can be found in the [FBO extension specification](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample/registry/EXT/framebuffer_object.txt) (look for Issue 87):

```
(87) What happens if a single image is attached more than once to a
     framebuffer object?

     RESOLVED: The value written to the pixel is undefined.

     There used to be a rule in section 4.4.4.2 that resulted in
     FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DUPLICATE_ATTACHMENT_EXT if a single
     image was attached more than once to a framebuffer object.

         FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DUPLICATE_ATTACHMENT_EXT   0x8CD8

         * A single image is not attached more than once to the
           framebuffer object.

           { FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DUPLICATE_ATTACHMENT_EXT }

     This rule was removed in version #117 of the
     EXT_framebuffer_object specification after discussion at the
     September 2005 ARB meeting.  The rule essentially required an
     O(n*lg(n)) search.  Some implementations would not need to do that
     search if the completeness rules did not require it.  Instead,
     language was added to section 4.10 which says the values
     written to the framebuffer are undefined when this rule is
     violated.
```

To fix this error, remove all usage of **GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DUPLICATE_ATTACHMENT_EXT** from your code.

If this isn't possible in your setup, then add a dummy definition to your **glext.h** or **glew.h** file like this:

```
#define GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DUPLICATE_ATTACHMENT_EXT 0x8CD8
```